# Select row of second table only if not exists in first one

Tags: mysql

I have two tables t1 and t2 with the same structure

```
id INT
userid INT
date DATETIME
```

The first table contains my data, while the second table is kind of helper table which contains rows for 10 fix dates and userid = -1
What i need is a SELECT which gives me all rows from t1 with userid=X joined(merged) with all rows from t2 which date is not already in the result of t1.

Pseudo code

```
SELECT id, date
FROM t1, t2
WHERE (t1.userid=:id OR t2.userid=-1) AND t2.date NOT IN t1.date
```

Sample:

t1:

```
id    userid     date
1     1          2015-12-01
2     1          2015-12-02
3     1          2015-12-03
4     2          2015-12-01
5     2          2015-12-02
```

t2:

```
id    userid    date
1     -1        2015-12-01
2     -1        2015-12-02
3     -1        2015-12-03
4     -1        2015-12-04
5     -1        2015-12-05
```

Expected output for userid=1:

```
1      1        2015-12-01
2      1        2015-12-02
3      1        2015-12-03
4     -1        2015-12-04
5     -1        2015-12-05
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I have added some sample

Comment: check  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join/6188334#6188334

Comment: I dont understand how this should be done with a join. Join only adds columns and not rows with the same columns.

Comment: user_id -1 How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a union select for doing this.

```
SELECT 
id, date
FROM 
t1
WHERE 
t1.id=:id
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
id, date
FROM 
t2
WHERE
t2.id=-1
AND t2.date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM t1 WHERE t1.userid=:id))
```